# Insert element into a 2D list in prolog

Tags: prolog

Given:

`List = [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]`

I want to make a method that does the following:

insert(a, 2, 3, List).

`List = [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, a, 0]]`

I figure this would involve recurring by rows then columns and decrement the respective variable until it is one as the base case, but what should be done after that? How is everything put back together?

Comment: You can't change the matrix (unless the entries start out as variables - but `0` is not a variable). You have to have an input and an output. Have you tried anything at all in Prolog to solve it?

Comment: @lurker: au contraire. Ouput is List, which is a variable, hence changing is not possible. It can easily be define by retrieving, the 3. element of the matrix-list. Replacing in this list the 2 element and than replacing the 3 element. The answer looks approximately 
`insert(Src,X,Y,Tar) :- get(Src,X,Foo),replace(Foo,Y, Bar),replace(Src,X,Bar)`

Comment: @CAFEBABE I probably didn't state my point clearly and, therefore, you misunderstood it. If the OP enters the matrix as shown with `0` in every cell, that specific matrix cannot be changed by a predicate. The predicate needs to have another argument with the new matrix. Alternatively, a matrix of variables could be used.

Comment: Mea culpa, indeed In fact I misread the authors post. Hence, my line is also wrong `insert(Src,Elem, X,Y,Tar) :- get(Src,X,Foo),replace(Foo,Elem, Y, Bar),replace(Src,Bar,X,Tar)` Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: How would i create a matrix of variables?

Comment: I figured it out, 
`mklist(Size, X):-
 length(X, Size),
 is(Itr, Size),
 filllist(Itr, Size, X).
filllist(0, _Size, _List).
filllist(Itr, Size, List):-
 is(Itr0, -(Itr, 1)),
 length(X, Size),
 nth1(Itr, List, X),
 filllist(Itr0, Size, List).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that is not the elegant answer, but I attempted to help you

this predicate `inserto/4` adds an element in one list

**Code**

```
inserto(_,[],[],_).
inserto(E,[_|Xs],[E|Ys],1) :- inserto(E,Xs,Ys,0),!.
inserto(E,[X|Xs],[X|Ys],N) :- N1 #= N-1,  % N<=length(List)
                              inserto(E,Xs,Ys,N1).
```

**Example :**

```
| ?- inserto(a,[1,2,3],L,1).
L = [a,2,3] ? ;
no
%
```

and this predicate `inserto/5` copy they elements of list L to L1 until N=M=0, it means we have to copy all elements of L into L1 until the new element must be replaced the ancient

**Code :**

```
% test : inserto(E,L,L1,N,M).
% test : L=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], inserto(e,L,L1,2,3).

inserto(_,[],[],_,_).
inserto(E,[[_|Xs]|Ys],[[E|Xs1]|Ys1],1,1) :-
                    !,inserto(E,[Xs|Ys],[Xs1|Ys1],0,0).

inserto(E,[[X]|Xs],[[X]|Xs1],0,0) :- 
                    inserto(E,Xs,Xs1,0,0),!.

inserto(E,[[X|Xs]|Ys],[[X|Xs1]|Ys1],0,0) :- 
                    inserto(E,[Xs|Ys],[Xs1|Ys1],0,0).  

inserto(E,[[X|Xs]|Ys],[[X|Xs1]|Ys1],N,1) :- 
                    N1 #= N-1,
                    inserto(E,[Xs|Ys],[Xs1|Ys1],N1,1).                                      

inserto(E,[Xs|Ys],[Xs|Ys1],N,M) :-  
                    M1 #= M-1,
                    inserto(E,Ys,Ys1,N,M1),!.
```

**Example :**

```
| ?- L=[[0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]], inserto(e,L,L1,3,2).
L = [[0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
L1 = [[0,0],[0,0,e],[0,0,0,0]] ? ;
no
```

according to your question I add this predicate `insert2D/4`

**Code :**

```
% test : insert2D('E',2,3,[[1,2],['R'],[a,b,c]]).

insert2D(Elem,NC,NL,List) :- 
                    inserto(Elem,List,NvList,NC,NL),
                    write(NvList).
```

**Example :**

```
| ?- insert2D('E',2,3,[[1,2],['R'],[a,b,c]]).
[[1,2],[R],[a,E,c]]
yes
```